# How to set checked properties false on checkbox array in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkboxlist

My chechkbox

```
  <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:15 !important;">
                            <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey checked disabled" style="position: relative;"><input class="alanlar" type="checkbox" disabled="" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" value="tarih" checked="" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                            <label class="control-label" style="margin-left: 5px;color:red;">Tarih</label>
                            </div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:15 !important;">
                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey checked disabled" style="position: relative;"><input class="alanlar" type="checkbox" disabled="" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" value="saat" checked="" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                        <label class="control-label" style="margin-left: 5px;color:red;">Saat</label>
                        </div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:15 !important;">
                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey checked disabled" style="position: relative;"><input class="alanlar" type="checkbox" disabled="" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" value="Order Adı" checked="" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                        <label class="control-label" style="margin-left: 5px;color:red;">Order Adı</label>
                        </div>
```

JQuery Lib

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Js Code

```
$("input[name='gunlukAlanlar[]']")[2].prop("checked", false);
```

But its not working.I'm want unchecked have index 2.But its not working.

Please review image
[image: Please review]

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't enter in a few houses due to internet access problems.I try now.But not fixed problem

Comment: I was updated my question.Please review new image

Comment: ok. I just adjusted my answer. See if that helps you.

Comment: Be more specific than "not working". What is happening? What isn't happening? What console errors do you get?

Comment: Not working again Kinglish.And not get console error.

Comment: $("input[name='gunlukAlanlar[]']")[2].prop("checked", false); I' trying again this.And error log

Comment: index.php?do=detayli_operasyon_raporu:943 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[2].prop is not a function
    at GunlukFiltreVarsayilan (index.php?do=detayli_operasyon_raporu:943)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.php?do=detayli_operasyon_raporu:1190)
GunlukFiltreVarsayilan @ index.php?do=detayli_operasyon_raporu:943
onclick @ index.php?do=detayli_operasyon_raporu:1190

Comment: I want just this."Varsayılana Çek" is button with set "Model Adı" checkbox unchecked

Comment: I was updated checkbox html codes.Please review again.Kinglish is code another html file is working.But not working my project.Maybe not working for chechkbox html.Please review my friends

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing an array index on a jQuery element collection (which doesn't work anyways) - stick with JQ and use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Also your code was setting an invisible checkbox (`opacity: 0`) to false (`prop("checked", false);`) - when they were all unchecked to begin with so ...

In this, I've set it so 'checked' checkboxes are visible. That is just a css class so it's easy to get rid of.

```js
$("input[name='gunlukAlanlar[]']").eq(1).prop("checked", false);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<label><input class="alanlar" type="checkbox" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" id="gunlukAlanlar[]" checked value="saat" /> //index 0</label>
<label><input class="alanlar" checked type="checkbox" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" id="gunlukAlanlar[]" value="modelii">//index 1</label>
<label><input class="alanlar" checked type="checkbox" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" id="gunlukAlanlar[]" value="tarih">//index 2</label>
<label><input class="alanlar" checked type="checkbox" name="gunlukAlanlar[]" id="gunlukAlanlar[]" value="musteri">//index 3</label>
```